# How to ignore a part of a JSON POST request

Tags: c#, json, post

I'm actually getting from an API information to do automatic trade.
Here is the code:

```
string webAddr = "https://shapeshift.io/sendamount";

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{ \"amount\" : \"1.08518719\", \"withdrawal\" : \"***SNIP***\", \"pair\" : \"eth_xmr\" }";

                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
            }
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                var apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(responseText);
                Console.WriteLine(responseText);
```

After execution, it's giving me this:

```
{"success":{"orderId":"6d8bcd05-57c5-4b8d-a4b5-c7080f3c84fd","pair":"eth_xmr","withdrawal":"***SNIP***","withdrawalAmount":"1.08518719","deposit":"0x93163985f6b4d4687ac7bc63d54016ed2d5f6aec","depositAmount":"0.34529822","expiration":1507244337386,"quotedRate":"3.20067447","maxLimit":16.79846053,"apiPubKey":"shapeshift","minerFee":"0.02"}}
```

When this appear, an other class is getting those information to put them into variable (Thanks Christos for that code)

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("orderId")]
    public static string orderId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pair")]
    public static string pair { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("withdrawal")]
    public static string withdrawal { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("withdrawalAmount")]
    public static string withdrawalAmount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("deposit")]
    public static string deposit { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("depositAmount")]
    public static string depositAmount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("expiration")]
    public static string expiration { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("quotedRate")]
    public static string quotedRate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("maxLimit")]
    public static string maxLimit { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("apiPubKey")]
    public static string apiPubKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("minerFee")]
    public static string minerFee { get; set; }
}
```

Problem is that it's not working. I think it's coming from the "SUCCESS" from the beginning of the response (with an other option from the API it's perfectly working) and I don't know how to "bypass" it to only get other information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move all the JSON properties to another class called 'Success' and this Success class needs to be within your API response class, since the properties are contained within the 'success' object. It would look something like this :

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    public Success success { get; set; }
}

public class Success
{
    [JsonProperty("orderId")]
    public static string orderId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pair")]
    public static string pair { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("withdrawal")]
    public static string withdrawal { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("withdrawalAmount")]
    public static string withdrawalAmount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("deposit")]
    public static string deposit { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("depositAmount")]
    public static string depositAmount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("expiration")]
    public static string expiration { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("quotedRate")]
    public static string quotedRate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("maxLimit")]
    public static string maxLimit { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("apiPubKey")]
    public static string apiPubKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("minerFee")]
    public static string minerFee { get; set; }
}
```

Tip : Visual Studio has a cool feature which gets you the objects from your JSON message. Go to your class editor, then from Edit Menu select option as Paste Special ->  Paste JSON as Classes.